# How to write own logic to initialize a property with Unity?

Tags: c#, .net, api, design-patterns, unity-container

Let's suppose you have Class A and Class B. 
Both these classes have a private variable:

`private Store _store {get;set}`

```
class Class A
{
 private Store _store {get;set}
 constructor()
 {
  init(param1,param2,..);
 }
 init(param1,param2,..)
 {
  //logic to initialize _store
 }
}

class Class B
{
 private Store _store {get;set}
 constructor()
 {
  init(param1,param2,..);
 }
 init(param1,param2,..)
 {
  //logic to initialize _store
 }
}
```

Problem: duplicate `init()` code

**My Solutions:**

1. **Simple Factory Pattern:** create a `StoreFactory` class with a `Init` method that will return a Store instance.
2. **Abstract Factory:** Create a Abstract Class that has init() method and let Class A and B inherit from it
3. ??

Is there a third way to achieve this? Perhaps with dependency injection container Unity? 
I would also be interested in knowing any other way of achieving this. With or without unity.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid the **inheritance**. **Composing** is likely to be easier for maintenance in the long run compared to the **inheritance**, for this reason i will prefer the factory approach or injecting some service into the classes.

Another approach will be to have the `Init` method as part of the `Store` class definition. And inject the `Store` class into the constructors of `Class A` and `B` (**Unity** will take care of the wiring).
Then you can call the `Init` method of the `Store` instead of relying on injecting the factory in each class where the store will be used.